# SpringBoot Integration with Mysql using Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am new to springboot and hibernate not able to figure out about different annotations and i understood that for additional settings like Database properties theres a file called application.properties in resources folder where we can set database url,username,password etc.

```
application properties
#Database
db.driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scm
db.username: root
db.password: password
# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql: true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create
```

But i came across a file DatabaseConfiguration.java which has code something like this.

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

 @Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfiguration {

  @Value("${db.driver}")
  private String DB_DRIVER;

   @Value("${db.password}")
   private String DB_PASSWORD;

   @Value("${db.url}")
   private String DB_URL;

   @Value("${db.username}")
   private String DB_USERNAME;

  @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
  private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

  @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
  private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

  @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
  private String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO;

  @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
  private String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
  LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
  sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
  sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
  Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return txManager;
}
```

}

Why should i mention database properties twice(In application properties,DatabaseConfig.java)

Why should i provide above methods with `@Bean` annotations and what is the relation between `@Bean` and `@Autowire` annotations and

there are some autowired annoatations like @UserDao which are not provided with @Bean annotations then how it is accepted where as for sessionFactory Autowiring im getting an acception like bean should be provided.

```
 package com.candidjava.spring.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.candidjava.spring.bean.User;
import com.candidjava.spring.dao.UserDao;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImp implements UserService {
@Autowired
UserDao userDao;


public List<User> getUser() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return userDao.getUser();
}

public User findById(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return userDao.findById(id);
}

public void createUser(User user) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    userDao.addUser(user);
}

public void deleteUserById(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    userDao.delete(id);
}
@Override
public User updatePartially(User user, int id) {
    userDao.updateCountry(user,id);
    return userDao.findById(id);
}

@Override
public User update(User user,int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return userDao.update(user, id);
}

}
```

Please explain the annotations used in DatabaseConfig like @value and what is HibernateTransactionmanager,Why is it required.

Comment: If you do not understand `@Bean`, @`Autowire` you should follow a basic spring tutorial first before trying anything else. This tutorial is good starting point (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/). If you search, you can find many other good tutorials.

Comment: @Johna,ok Thank you but please explain why i need to mention datasource properties twice in properties file and DatasourceConfig.java

Comment: It is not setting database properties twice. You mention username, password etc. in application.properties file and access those values in DatabaseConfig.java. `@Value("${db.username}") private String DB_USERNAME` gets the value you have set for `db.username` and initialize `DB_USERNAME` with it. In spring boot you don't need to it though, because database  settings in your `application.properties` file are read and used in relevant places automatically.

Comment: But i tried doing that,it is saying that for Autowiring sessionFactory,i need a bean which i created in the configuration class,but still it is not identified properly.How to autowire sessionFactory

Comment: That is why asked you to learn the basics first. Please try a good tutorial. If not, you are going to encounter a series of problems to get this code to run.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use **application.properties** in order to configure my Spring Boot Application, as a more efficient way to maintain it and even to define more than a profile.

Your sample DatabaseConfiguration.java file is a way to force your application to read the properties programatically, and also adds some of your logic if needed.